# Volley: Pause/Resume Download

Tags: android, imagedownload, android-volley

I'm using a `Volley` for Loading Images. However, I want to pause Image Download on listview `fling`.

Is there a way to pause/resume `Request Queue` in Volley.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volley's RequestQueue has methods `start()` and `stop()` so it hould be called in `onScrollStateChanged()` method in next way:

```
if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
    mRequestQueue.stop();
} else {
    mRequestQueue.start();
}
```

Comment: This is a heavy-weight solution, trading load image calls for nearly constant rescans of the cache directory. Check it out in DDMS, it is pretty brutal.

Comment: It causes stoping all request. Is there a way stopping the spesificied request?